# Adding and removing fragments dynamically in ViewPager

Tags: android, adapter, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a `ViewPager` with a custom `PagerFragmentAdapter` that uses an internal list to provide fragments. I would like to add and remove fragments dynamically on settings changes.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);
    mAdapter = new ServicePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

I have tried to call again the `setAdapter` but I obtain an `IllegalStateException (Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState)`.

How can achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reset your `ServicePagerAdapter` every time. It's enough to create and set it once in `onCreate()` method of your `Activity` (or in `onActivityCreated()` method of your `Fragment`) and then you can simply call `add()` method of your adapter to add new elements to it. But don't forget to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after every addition to adapter.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not so easy. FragmentPagerAdapter caches Fragments, you have to create a custom PagerAdapter or use some tricks.

Comment: in your code sample you mention `ServicePagerAdapter` - this is not a library class, so I assumed you already using custom adapter. So yes, you need custom implementation of `PagerAdapter` class. Regarding your main question - I think it was answered.

Comment: It's not enough to call notifyDataSetChanged() on the PagerAdapter if elements have been removed.  You need to also override the getItemPosition method of the PagerAdapter.  Return POSITION_UNCHANGED if element is still there, or POSITION_NONE if it has been removed.